# Blazor security get user unique identifier

Tags: blazor, asp.net-identity

I am using scaffolded Identity to add registered restrictions to my Blazor Server app.

Whilst I found many threads as to how to retrieve identified user *NAME* in the application, I struggle to find documentation as to how to retrieve the registered users' unique identifier (`AspNetUsers.Id` field).

Is there a built-in way, or should I query the table based on the user name?

NOTE: checking the structure, there is no `unique` constraint on `UserName`. There is a check when registering users - but still, I'd rather not go with the assumption the user name is unique!

Comment: About the case of unique `UserName`, I hope you can go with the assumption `UserName` are unique, otherwise how would you know which user to login?

Comment: You can get your connected user through the cascading parameter `Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask`, (if you correctly wrapped your app with `<CascadingAuthenticationState></CascadingAuthenticationState>`): `(await authenticationStateTask).User.Id` (when not null obviously).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in the components:

```
@context.User.Claims.First().Value
```

For Example:

```
<AuthorizeView>
<Authorized>
    @*UserId*@
    @context.User.Claims.First().Value
    <a class="logout-btn login-btn-improved" href="Security/Logout">Logout</a>
</Authorized>
<NotAuthorized>
    <a class="login-btn login-btn-improved" href="userregister">Register</a>
    <a class="login-btn login-btn-improved" href="login">Login</a>
</NotAuthorized>
```

If you use the `AuthenticationStateProvider` you can get the user id in the class as follows:

```
public async Task<int?> GetUserIdAsync()
    {
 var authenticationState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
 if (!authenticationState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return 0;
 return Convert.ToInt32(authenticationState.User.Claims?.First().Value)
}
```